# My nested For-Each loop isn't going through each cell in a given range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

In Excel VBA:

My second For-Each loop is only going through the first cell in a given column.
I need help getting it to go through each cell in the entire column.

In my code included here, I want to loop through each cell in a row (no issue). then once a cell in the row matches my criteria (no issue), I want to loop through each cell (celltwo) in that cell's column (issue).

I'm able to loop through the row and identify my criteria, but then the second for-each loop only considers the first celltwo in the given column. So I never get a celltwo with .row >=10, the first cell in each column has row=1.

Any help is appreciated.

This is for VBA in Excel. I've tried different ways of identifying my second range to loop through but nothing has allowed the second for-each loop to cycle back from "Next Celltwo" to the beginning of the loop.

```
Sub WriteSummary()
Dim UploadRange As Range
Dim SummaryRow As Integer
Dim CategoryRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Celltwo As Range

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Set Variables
    Set MacroFile = ThisWorkbook
    Set MacroSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro")
    Set UploadDash = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload Dash")
    Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set IndexSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Indexes")
    Set CategoryRange = UploadDash.Range("5:5")
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Determine Output Row
SummaryRow = SummarySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

''''''MY PROBLEM STARTS HERE'''''''

For Each Cell In CategoryRange
If Cell.Value = 8840 Then
    For Each Celltwo In SummarySheet.Cells(, Cell.Column).EntireColumn
                i = MsgBox(Celltwo.Row, vbOKOnly)
        If Celltwo.Row >= 10 Then

            If Celltwo.Value > 0 Then
            o = MsgBox(Celltwo.AddressLocal)

                SummaryRow = SummaryRow + 1
            Else
            End If
        Else

        End If
    Next Celltwo '''''DOES NOT LOOP'''''
Else
End If
Next Cell
```

I expect that when the code finds cell.value = 8840 it will then loop through each cell in that cell's column. Instead, it only loops through the first cell in that column and exits the second for-each loop

Comment: `Option Explicit`. Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cells` needs a row and column argument, but I think it's the `EntireColumn` which is taking the whole column as a single range.

Try something like this instead, which will restrict to cells containing something.

It starts at row 6 so amend to suit.

```
With SummarySheet
    For Each Celltwo In .Range(.Cells(6, Cell.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Cell.Column).end(xlup))
        ' etc
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks SJR, referencing the range in this manner got me going. I also had a serious reference issue - "CellTwo" is in the "UploadDash" worksheet object not the "SummarySheet" worksheet object - New Year, same me

Comment: Forgot dot before `Rows.Count` 